# Issue with casting a date in query object addParam using cfscript

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am creating a query using `cfscript` syntax, and I have two query parameters that are dates.  I created the date string the first time using

```
queryservice.addParam(
     name="last_update",
     value="createODBCDate(now())",
     cfsqltype="cf_sql_date");
```

I would assume this would an analogue to:

```
<cfqueryparam value="#createODBCDate(now())#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
```

So, when I run the query, I'm getting:

```
The cause of this output exception was that: coldfusion.runtime.Cast$DateStringConversionException: The value createODBCDate(now()) cannot be converted to a date.
```

Fine. So I created a variable,

```
var currentDate = createODBCDate(now());
```

added it to

```
queryservice.addParam(
     name="last_update",
     value="createODBCDate(now())",
     cfsqltype="cf_sql_date");
```

and got

```
The cause of this output exception was that: coldfusion.runtime.Cast$DateStringConversionException: The value currentDate cannot be converted to a date.
```

When I created the query using the standard `<cfquery ...` syntax it worked fine.

So, I'm assuming that I am doing something wrong, but I can't for the life of me figure out what that is.

By the way, this is really my first time trying to create a query using the `<cfscript>` syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `value="createODBCDate(now())"`

You forgot the # signs around the function. Without those, it is just a string. So the function is never invoked and you end up passing in the literal characters "createODBCDate(now())" as the date `value`.

**Update:**

As an aside, `cf_sql_date` automatically removes any time portion. So while using `createODBCDate` will not hurt anything, it is redundant. You could simply write:

```
    queryservice.addParam(
         name="last_update",
         value="#now()#",
         cfsqltype="cf_sql_date");
```

Comment: So I guess it is an issue of when to use the `#` in a cfscript block. As I said, this is the first time that I am using cfscript to create a query.

Comment: No, it is not really related to `cfscript`. You need # signs whenever you use a CF variable (ie that must be evaluated) within quotes. Notice, you used # signs in your `cfqueryparam` example because the function is embedded within double quotes.

Comment: I see that now.  I just figured that they were not needed inside a cfscript tags for some reason. thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you could omit them and write it as ie `name="last_update", value=now() ,...` . Personally I do not like that mixed style, but it is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt needs #'s just like @Leigh mentioned and also didn't reference the variable "currentDate" that you created.

Comment: True, though in this case you could skip the extra variable. In fact, you could just use `value="#now()#"` because `cf_sql_date` automatically removes the time. So `createODBCDate` is redundant.